# When to use `/` and when to use `\` in regards to path Python

Tags: python, cmd, path, operating-system

I have a few questions regarding to the path in Python using `os` module:

(1) If using `os` module, is there any difference between `\` and `/` in regards to the absolute path of a file?

For examples:

```
import os 
example_path_1 = "C:\abc\def"
example_path_2 = "C:/abc/def"
```

a. Can `os.system(example_path_1)` and `os.system(example_path_2)` both work?

b. Can `os.mkdir(example_path_1)` and `os.mkdir(example_path_2)` both work?

(2) When using the `os` module in Python, if I'm getting this right, it seems in some situations we have to use `/`, and the other situations we have to use `\`. How to tell the difference?

Comment: No. In all situations you should use /. On Windows, \ also works, but you will run into trouble as that is also the escape character.

Comment: You can use `os.path.sep` which will give you the right character for the current platform.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Goyo  Sometimes it successes but sometimes it doesn't. Thats why I'm really confused of what to use... Also sometimes I saw some codes with a `r` in front of the path, but I don't really understand why to put that?

Comment: @ryan9025 Use the path separator as defined in your operating system (but use it properly). Use `os.path.sep` for cross platform code.

Comment: With file system functions, you can use forward slash, except never with "\\\\?\\" paths because this prefix bypasses path normalization. Regarding `os.system` and `subprocess`, when parsing their command lines, there are still some programs that require backslash in paths. It's best to either use backslash or forward slash plus `os.path.normpath` with command lines. Registry paths also must use backslash.

Comment: Thanks guys! So if I'm getting this correct that it's safe to use forward slash  
/ besides a few exceptions? Also, should I put `r` before these paths even with forward slash?

Comment: You don't need a raw path with forward slashes. And using a raw path won't help with paths that end in backslash -- e.g. `r"C:\"` is a syntax error. Raw paths are also no good for `unicode` strings in Python 2 since `\u` and `\U` escapes are still processed (e.g. `ur'C:\Users'` is a syntax error), and using Unicode for file paths in Windows is very important.

Comment: @eryksun Appreciated!  So raw path shouldn't really be used in python `os` module?  Also I'm really new to this Unicode or Unix (actually I don't have any idea what that is), could you pls provide some documentations or videos about it if you have any? Thanks!!

Comment: Prefer `os.path.join` or forward slashes, or `normpath` when needed.

Comment: As to Unicode, natively Windows uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) strings for file-system and registry paths, environment variables, command lines, etc. There's a legacy ANSI / MBCS API (a legacy from MS-DOS and 16-bit Windows), but it's limited to the system locale's ANSI codepage, such as the single-byte 1252 codepage (about 250 characters). The ANSI API 'solves' this problem by using best-fit conversions (e.g. "α" => "a") or just a bunch of question marks. It's horrible and should be avoided always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be safe with always sticking to forward slashes

```
example_path = "/c/abc/def"
```

If you use windows style, you need to escape them or use a raw string

```
example_path = "C:\\abc\\def"
example_path = r"C:\abc\def"
```

In general, stick to doing as much as you can in the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module, it will handle these OS-specific issues fairly robustly. For example you can pass a path to [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) and it will normalize your slashes to whatever platform you're on. Similarly building up paths with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will insert the correct slashes for your system.

Comment: Im new to this so sorry that I kinda don't get why your example_path missing the `C:`?  Could you please provide a example that if I want to change directory/make new directory to `C:\abc\def` (or in even much more complicated case) in Windows, what is the safest way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @ryan9025 The first version is a "unix style" path, the second is a "windows style" path, but python will work with a unix style path on a windows system.

Comment: Thanks! So that means in both cases that `os.path` will always work?